# How do I take two at a time from a collection

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to create substrings from each index in a string using this helper method

```
public  List<int> AllIndexesOf(string str, string value)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        throw new ArgumentException("the string to find may not be empty", "value");
    List<int> indexes = new List<int>();
    for (int index = 0; ; index += value.Length)
    {
        index = str.IndexOf(value, index);
        if (index == -1)
            return indexes;
        indexes.Add(index);
    }
}
```

And the way I am using it is like this

```
string input = "27758585926302004842";
List<int> eh = AllIndexesOf(input, "2");
```

So I essentially want to grab each string between the indexes in two.

So the subscring between index 0 and 9 and 13 and 19.

I'm just not sure how to do this without using linq

Comment: consider using a regex?

Comment: Trying to do this without linq and regex and just like a pure way if that makes any sense

Comment: @VargaDev _Why?_ What's wrong with LINQ?

Comment: Nothing I love linq, but I just want to try to do this without any extensions like regex or linq

Comment: So given a `List<int>` and a input string, you want to return the substrings of that input, given the indexes are actual pairs in `List<int>` ?

Comment: I do not understand where “substrings” are used here. The awkward loop simply returns the “index” of the character that matches `value`. What “substrings” are you trying to obtain from `str`? This comment… _”So I essentially want to grab each string between the indexes in two.”_ … makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the problem, you just need to jump 2 in a for loop

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetSubStrings(string input, List<int> source)
{
   for (var i = 0; i < source.Count; i += 2)
      yield return input.Substring(source[i], source[i + 1] - source[i]);
}
```

or if you don't want to use an iterator method

```
public static List<string> GetSubStrings2(string input, List<int> source)
{
    var result = new List<string>();
    for (var i = 0; i < source.Count; i += 2)
      result.Add(input.Substring(source[i], source[i + 1] - source[i]));
    return result;
}
```

**Usage**

```
var input = "2abcdef2ggg2abcdefgh2";
var indexes = AllIndexesOf(input, "2");

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", GetSubStrings(input, indexes)));
```

**Output**

```
2abcdef, 2abcdefgh
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bw2Hbc)